# Seeking Hadoop-based object mapping for Grails with pessamistic locking

Tags: hadoop, grails, mapreduce, locking

I would like to add map reduce functionality to my Grails application using pessimistic locking. I began to port my application to MongoDB using the standard Grails plugin and was disappointed to see the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Datastore [org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoCodecSession] does not support locking.
```

I have looked into alternate MongoDB plugins, the DynamoDB plugin and the CouchDB plugin but I am not seeing any information explicitly indicating if pessimistic locking is supported. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Update: It turns out Cassandra supports Map-Reduce (I had no idea). According to the Cassandra Grails plugin documentation, the plugin supports  "Session-managed transactions". I believe this will support pessimistic locking. I will update this question with my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to add my own pessimistic locking layer using the Redis distributed lock plugin to implement my own concurrency data structures. It was a bit of a pain but it provides improved performance and allows me to use any back-end Gorm plug in I choose.

Hopefully this helps in someones design decision.